# Loud hum when input is connected to amp

Tags: amplifier, hum

I've just built a JLH 1969 amplifier kit that I bought online. When connected to the stereo output of my phone (isolating one channel at a time) the amp works fine one channel at a time but when I connect the input ground of both channels together there's a loud hum (and the input audio is barely audible when I hook it up in stereo with the hum taking over)

Also, I noticed as soon as I connect the  input ground to input ground on both channels the mains power consumption on the toroid spikes to 150w. It runs around 60w when there's no input (when both channels are powered) please see image for reference. I just want to know how to fix the hum and provide a stereo input.
[image]

Schematic

[image]

[image]

Power line wiring above

Close up

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You never mentioned what device or which devices you connect to the input and how you connect them.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. I was connecting to my phone.

Comment: I'm just a hobbyist, not sure what other details you might require to help you answer.

Comment: Are both powered by the same winding of the transformer? Did you by any chance swap line and neutral between both channels?

Comment: Toroid is a 18v-0v-18v center tap. If you look at the pic. The two red wires are the live I presume and the black shared between both being the center tap? I've added a close up pic of the power connection.

Comment: 2 out of the 4 connectors are speaker outs. I'm curious if these need two separate toroids?

Comment: Well the pictures don't show the input connections for instance. We would also need to guess which pins are which on each connector. Which are ground, which are signal, etc.

Comment: There's a picture of the schematics of a single channel if that helps.

Comment: What do the kit instructions tell you about having isolated AC feeds to the bridge rectifiers when using two channels. Concentrate on that because, at the moment, that is your problem.

Comment: It doesn't say much.. this is the link to the item
https://a.aliexpress.com/_mtFsAs6

Comment: @Ahsan The schematics won't help as you don't know in which orientation the connectors are on PCB. The schematics also don't tell how you connected the boards together and to your phone.

Comment: Not written in the question, but there's another thing you are asking: You ask troubles by soldering wire ends and then tightening them under screws. The solder is plastic and flows gradually out making you connections loose. It can take months, even years, but it will happen. Instead of solder use ferrules. Get a crimper plier tool to do it fast and reliably.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can add a second winding manually to your transformer. Wind 20 turns, measure the voltage, calculate the really needed turns. It is not that hard to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The boards are connected together before the rectifier. Since their grounds are also tied together via the audio inputs, this makes a rather complicated but viable path for the current to flow via the two rectifiers, and that shorts your transformer.

[image]

Even if that didn't cause excess current to flow, the rectifier current pulses will still flow in the audio signal ground wire, which means you will get a ton of hum.

Solution: look closer at the transformer. Usually "center tapped" transformers really have two secondary windings coming out, and they're just joined outside the transformer. Just split them, so you have two independent secondaries, and feed each amp from one secondary. They will now be isolated from each other, and this problem will be solved.

Comment: If a single winding can handle the load, OP might also connect both channels in parallel, and leave the other winding unused.

Comment: Thank bob for helping. I'll try it out in a while and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @polwel That will cause AC current to flow in the audio signal ground wire between the boards and cause hum. It's quite difficult to make two amplifier boards work well with one transformer, usually the way is to use only one set of rectifier+caps...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a transformer with isolated secondaries.

[image]

However, the existing transformer may be salvaged using two external diodes of adequate rating. The common supply could then be fed to both the boards after disconnecting the bridge rectifiers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer is also very valid. In summery I might try to split the toroid at the center tap, Or make a single supply and share between the channels and remove the bridge rectifiers. Or buy an entirely separate toroid for the second channel.

Comment: Anytime, Ahsan.